# How to show a comment box on checkout page in netsuite

Tags: comments, checkout, netsuite

How can I show a custom comment box on a checkout page in netsuite. I am a newbie in netsuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom "Transaction Body Field" by going to Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Transaction Body Field.

Select type "Free-Form Text" and make sure to select the "web store" checkbox.

This will show up on the checkout process on the Review and Submit Your Order page.